# Trying to run methods after api starts up

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

So I've written an api on ASP.Net-Core and I want to run some csvReader methods as soon as the server starts. Currently it just starts up and doesn't run my DataMigrationController.

```
class Program
{
    public const string _path =
        "C://path";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("https://localhost:44301/")
            .Build()
            .Run();

        DataMigrationController DMC = new DataMigrationController();
        DMC.readCSV(_path);
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Comment: The server runs successfully

Comment: I notice that ou are using the _https_ protocol, have you done the additional work to setup the certificates for the server to use? Maybe [this helps](https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2018/07/09/aspnetcore-ssl.html).

Comment: Yes I have, I have a fully configured Startup.cs file. The API runs fine, I just want to run these methods without having to create new endpoints to hit. I want to run it on startup to populate the connected DB with the csv file provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#manage-the-host), it appears as if the `Run()` method is blocking; you would want to use `Start()` instead.

Comment: I run into this error when using run:
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Comment: Then assume the same will happen with the other library - seems you are unable to establish a connection to the SQL server, and that's a different issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/).

You can set a job that will be performed only once after starting the app. See Fire-and-forget jobs in hangfire documentation.

Just be careful not to add too many job clone to the queue. You can easily avoid this by using the WorkerCount option. For more info look:
https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-degree-of-parallelism.html

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Why use a dedicated thread and additional libraries when you have the option to just not call the blocking method?